# Azure.Identity Vulnerability - Remote Code Execution (RCE)

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have a .NET 7.0 project which uses Entity Framework and therefore references the package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SQLServer which in turn calls Microsoft.Data.SQLClient and that calls Azure.Identity ( version 1.7.0 ). All these packages are the latest version and our vulnerability scanning tool detected Azure.Identity as being highly vulnerable due to Remote Code Execution (RCE) (https://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=CVE-2023-36414).

From my end I cannot think about what else I can do other than to heavily downgrade Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SQLServer  or remove it completely and find an alternative.

Did someone find a solution to this problem please?

Comment: Just add an explicit reference to the latest version of Azure.Identity

Comment: Fix is on it's way - https://github.com/dotnet/sqlclient/issues/2198